# Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I have a search bar, and in the debug console `Snapshotting a view (0x7f91b1e2a200, _UIReplicantView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.` keeps printed whenever I click caps:↑.

There was no problem at all before I started using UISearchBar.

I only print what is inside of the search bar

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   print(searchBar.text!)
}
```

I found this question [Snapshotting a view (_UIReplicantView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686425/snapshotting-a-view-uireplicantview-that-has-not-been-rendered-at-least-once), but the answers didn't solve my problem.